# Fitting Bayesian Hierarchical Models in rSTAN

Tags: regression, bayesian, hierarchical-bayesian, stan, rstan

The model I have is $$
\begin{align*}
y_{ij} & \sim Normal\left(\alpha_j + \beta x_i, \sigma^2\right)\\
\alpha_j &\sim Normal\left(\gamma_0 + \gamma_1 u_j, \tau^2\right)
\end{align*}
$$ Where $$ \begin{align*}
\beta, \gamma_0, \gamma_1 & \sim Normal\left(0, 0.25^2\right)\\
\sigma, \tau & \sim Normal_+\left(0, 0.75^2\right).
\end{align*}
$$

I need to fit this model using STAN. My first thought was to use rstanarm. My code for that is

```
data(radon)
library(rstan)
library(rstanarm)

fit <- stan_glmer(log_radon ~ (1 | county) + floor, data=radon,
                  prior = normal(0, 0.25, autoscale = FALSE,
                  prior_aux = normal(0, 0.75, autoscale = FALSE))
```

I'm not entirely sure if this properly models the $\alpha_j$ portion of my model.

Comment: Your question is a good one, although it will probably get marked as off-topic because it focuses on code rather than concepts (although the two are very intertwined with probabilistic programming languages like Stan). In any event, you need to add a `prior_intercept = normal(0, 0.25, autoscale = FALSE)` to implement your prior on $\gamma_0$.

Comment: @BenGoodrich That’s what I ended up doing! Still nice to hear that I got to the correct place. Thank you.